# Json deserialize key/value dictionary

Tags: vb.net, serialization, json.net

I saw the "Similar question" but trying all of them did not solve my problem.
I have a Json like this

```
{
    "externalId": "pobj124",
    "dossierNumber": "Test 20210216",
    "issuedDate": "2021-01-28T23:00:00+00:00",
    "issuedPlace": "New-York",
    "properties": {
        "documentTypeId": 7,
        "countryLayout": "US"
    }
}
```

The properties is an unknown number of "name": "value". Not knowing neither the name nor the value.
My class is defined as

```
<Serializable>
Public Class Document
    Public Property externalId As String
    Public Property dossierNumber As String
    Public Property issuedDate As Date
    Public Property issuedPlace As String
    Public Property properties As IDictionary(Of String, String)
End Class
```

The calling code is

```
Private Function DeserializeJson(json As String) As Document
    Return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of Document)(json)
End Function
```

It seems that it is not the right way to deserialize a dictionary.
Error is

> Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type
> 'Document' because the type requires a JSON object (e.g.
> {"name":"value"}) to deserialize correctly. To fix this error either
> change the JSON to a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) or change the
> deserialized type to an array or a type that implements a collection
> interface (e.g. ICollection, IList) like List that can be
> deserialized from a JSON array. JsonArrayAttribute can also be added
> to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON array.

What I've tried so far:

```
Public Property properties As IDictionary(Of String, String)
Public Property properties As List(Of KeyValuePair(Of String, String))
Public Property properties As Dictionary(Of String, String)
Public Property properties() As KeyValuePair(Of String, String)
```

Comment: This error is not related to the Dictionary, but the JSON Object itself, which seems to be part of an Array. Post the complete JSON.

Comment: Can't reproduce, see https://dotnetfiddle.net/avWPPM.  The JSON in your question can be deserialized to the type `Document` in your question.  Please [edit] your question to share a [mcve].  Presumably the JSON that actually causes the problem includes an array somewhere, as mentioned by Jimi.

Comment: Ok, you're right, I've some arrays.
I've change them to List(Of and it is now deserializing my Dictionary.
The error was confusing me because it was in a class with only Dictionary properties but the class itself was used in a array.
Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was in the definition of the underlying classes.
One was defined as

```
Public Class PartialClass
    Public Property goods() As Product
End Class

Public Class Product
    Public Property caracteristics As IDictionnary(Of String, String)
End Class
```

when it should be

```
Public Class PartialClass
    Public Property goods As List(Of Product)
End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

have tried Something similar like below on vb.net. Use BsonTypeMapper.MapToDotNetValue.

JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(BsonTypeMapper.MapToDotNetValue(**a(i)**.ToString().Replace("\n", "||")))

Comment: No, I did not. I've solved my issue, it was not related to Dictionary but to a Property defined as

Public Property goods() As Product

wich, replaced by 

Public Property goods As List(Of Product)

is working.

Comment: @Skippy If you have found the answer for your own question then please leave a post with the solution. Do not use comment section for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

This drove me to insanity when I was trying to figure it out with no answers.   What worked for me is I removed “Property” from Arrays and Lists within the class and left the Public Keyword only.

Comment: There is my answer. Replace arrays with List(Of.That was enough for me and solved my problem.